# C# - Default Comparer not working as expected when sorting one list by another

Tags: c#, list, sorting, icomparable

I have two lists as follows (this is a simplified example):

```
var dataList = new List<char>{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
var sortList = new List<int>{ 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
```

Here's what my sorting method looks like:

```
void SortOneListByAnother<T1, T2>(List<T1> dataList, List<T2> sortList)
    where T1 : IComparable
    where T2 : IComparable
{
    dataList.Sort((a, b) => sortList[dataList.IndexOf(a)].CompareTo(sortList[dataList.IndexOf(b)]));
}
```

This *should* return dataList (the list of characters) sorted in the same way that sortList is sorted (in this case, reverse order), i.e.:

```
{ 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a' }
```

Instead, my code appears to be ignoring the first and last elements of the list (while properly sorting everything in between); thus I am getting:

```
{ 'a', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'f' }
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Arrays and lists have a zero-based indexing. So, try instead, sortList = new List<int> { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 }

Comment: Remember that the first element in a list is at index 0, not index 1.

Comment: On a sidenote, the way you sort is pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that List.Sort performs the sort in-place, so when your comparison calls `dataList.IndexOf(a)`, the elements are already partially sorted, so you get undefined behavior.

You need to make a copy of the original dataList and use it to lookup the index during the sort.

Sample code:

```
void SortOneListByAnother<T1, T2>(List<T1> dataList, List<T2> sortList)
    where T1 : IComparable
    where T2 : IComparable
{
    var lookupList = new List<T1>(dataList);
    dataList.Sort((a, b) => sortList[lookupList.IndexOf(a)].CompareTo(sortList[lookupList.IndexOf(b)]));
}
```

On a side note, this sort algorithm probably has O(n^3) worst-case time complexity.

Comment: And using `OrderBy` would be a fix because it materializes the sort keys once.

Comment: Thanks; this works.  I would like to take your suggestion and use OrderBy rather than Sort.  But the signature for OrderBy is different; I can't figure how to pass in a Comparer.  If I do this:

Comment: If I do this:
dataList = dataList.OrderBy(x => x, (a, b) => sortList[dataList.IndexOf(a)].CompareTo(sortList[dataList.IndexOf(b)]));

Comment: Then I get this error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<T1>' because it is not a delegate type